# Webservice IIS and permissions 401 Error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have an issue I do not understand

I have a Webservices (not WCF) in two different locations, my localhost and our development server.

My localhost is running

XP SP3 
IIS 5.1

Dev Server is running

Windows Server 2003 SP 2 
IIS 6.0

Directory Security in IIS for Both is Anonymous Access and Integrated Windows authentication

My issue is when I run the following code from inside VS2010

```
Dim ws As RunExternalProcess.ProcessExecution = New RunExternalProcess.ProcessExecution
ws.Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationValue(KEY_VALUE_PROCESS_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS))
ws.ExecuteProcess (BusinessClasses.RunExternalProcess.enuProcessType.EFTCreateFile, PROC_POST, strParameters)
```

When the webservice is pointed to the Dev server it runs fine.  When pointed to my local I get a HTTP 401 error

if I add the line

```
 ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

it works fine for my local.  The question I need to answer before I deploy it is why do I need the credentials line if it works fine accessing the dev web service today.  And what is different about my local?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not allowing [anonymous access](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/02/21/70212.aspx) for your local server.

By default the client side copies the credentials/proxy settings of your Internet Explorer so you might want to check those too.

Comment: I double triple checked I am allowing annon access.  IE has no proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen URL scan do some weird stuff too, if you're running URL scan check to see if any of those settings are preventing access to it.